# Goals not working Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have the following url: http:// domain.com/subdirectory/ for my website. I have set goals in 3 different ways and none seems to work.

```
    1- /subdirectory/goal.php
    2- /goal.php
    3- goal.php
```

Notice that the settings in traffic info for my website is not the full URL domain.com I have a shared hosting so the web that I want to track is under http:// domain.com/subdirectory/

Comment: Solved. No matter where the goal page is located. Must include all the path after the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Google actually did a fairly good job explaining this exact problem here: 
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033158?hl=en

Most likely the "The Goal page is not tagged with tracking code".